# Easy way to combine string resources with databinding

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I can initialise text in my [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) in the following way using **string resources**:

```
android:text="@string/my_text"
```

And this is how I would do that using two way **data-binding**:

```
android:text="@={viewModel.myText}"
```

The question is how to combine above approaches (if it's possible) in order to have EditText initialized with "@string/my_text" and in the same time benefit from two way data-binding? Basically I'm looking for something like below (however it only works in preview, not in the app):

```
android:text="@={viewModel.myText, default=@string/my_text}"
```

I know that I can use second approach and in ViewModel initialize myText which will be propagated to view but I wonder if it's possible to achieve that only in xml?

In my opinion the benefit would be that ViewModel wouldn't have to know about string resources.

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: @kgandroid unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

The way we handle in our project in ViewModel code behind :

- set a default text to 'myText' in ViewModel and,
- whenever we require updating the value, call:

  public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
      notifyPropertyChanged(BR.passwordQuality);
  }

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: First thing is that you are probably using one way data-binding with "@{viewModel.myText}". I am using two way databinding with "@={viewModel.myText}", so I don't need to manually call notifyPropertyChanged. Second thing is that I know that I can set default text to 'myText' in ViewModel, however my default text is in @string resources and in order to get it I would have to access context from ViewModel, which I would like to avoid.